# How Can I Use Validation In the given code

Tags: reactjs, redux

How Can I implement Validation here in this code? I tried Using Various methods, but it is causing errors. How Can I implement Validation here, I have tried by using validate but its also causing error.

Here I have made addTodo Form.

`addTodoForm.js`:

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {addTodo} from '../redux/todoSlice';




const AddTodoForm = () => {
    
    const [value, setValue] = useState('');

    const [item,setItem]=useState('');

    const [item2,setItem2]=useState('');

    const dispatch= useDispatch();

    


    const onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(addTodo({
            title: value,
            title1: item,
            title2:item2
        }))
    };




    

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className='form-inline mt-3 mb-3'>
            
            <p>Name</p>
            <input
                type='text'
                
                className='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2'
                placeholder='Add todo...'
                value={value}
                
                onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
                
            ></input>
            

            <p style={{marginLeft:"100px"}}>Fruits</p>
            <select style={{marginTop:"-10px",marginLeft:"5px"}} 
            value={item} className='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2'
            onChange={(event) => setItem(event.target.value)}>

            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option selected value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
            </select>

            <p style={{marginLeft:"30px"}}>Gender</p>
            <label style={{marginLeft:"20px",marginTop:"-10px"}} 
            value={item2} className='form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2'
            onChange={(event) => setItem2(event.target.value)}>

            <input type="radio" value="Male" name="gender" /> Male
            <input style={{marginLeft:"5px"}} type="radio" value="Female" name="gender" /> Female
            <input style={{marginLeft:"5px"}} type="radio" value="Other" name="gender" /> Other
            </label>
            
            <button style={{marginLeft:"20px",marginTop:"-20px"}} type='submit' >
                Submit
            </button>

            
        </form>
    );
};

export default AddTodoForm;
```

Here I am using the reducers to change the state:

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const todoSlice=createSlice({
    name:'todos',
    initialState:[
        {id:1, title:"todo1", completed: false},
        {id:2, title:"todo2", completed: false},
        {id:3, title:"todo3", completed: true}     
    ],
    reducers:{
        addTodo:(state,action)=>{
            const newTodo={
                id:Date.now(),
                title:action.payload.title,
                title1:action.payload.title1,
                title2:action.payload.title2,
                completed:false
            };
            state.push(newTodo);
        },
        deleteTodo:(state,action)=>{
           return state.filter((todo)=> todo.id !==action.payload.id)
        }
    }

})

export const {addTodo,toggleComplete,deleteTodo}=todoSlice.actions;

export default todoSlice.reducer;
```

Here I have used `useSelector` to get all the data in todos and have mapped.

`todoList.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const TodoList = () => {

    const todos= useSelector((state)=>state.todos)


    return (
        <ul>
    
            {todos.map((todo) => (
                <TodoItem id={todo.id} title={todo.title} completed={todo.completed} title1={todo.title1}  title2={todo.title2}/>
            ))}
        
        </ul>
    );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: I am trying to implement validation in it, but its not getting executed there.  const required=v =>{
  if(!v || v===''){
    return 'This field is Required'
  }

  return undefined;
}   and after it i am calling required in my components for validation